# What does "\" mean in math

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In a Linear Algebra textbook I am reading, the following is stated: $b\notin \operatorname{span}(A \cup \{a\})\setminus \operatorname{span}(A)$. It does so without explaining what "$\setminus$" means. I apologize if this question does not belong here but I just want to understand what it means. I can close the question if someone just comments on its meaning.

Comment: @André: [*apologise* is the correct spelling in British English](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apologise).

Answer (score 10):

$\setminus$ (`\setminus`) as its name implies is the set-theoretic difference: $A\setminus B$ is the set of all elements which are in $A$ but not in $B$. ($A-B$ is also used for this.) Be careful to not confuse $\setminus$ with $/$ (quotient).

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are two sets, then
$A \setminus B$ means the set that contains all those elements of $A$ that are not in $B$.
Guess this is what you talking about..