# Does $A\setminus B = A\setminus C$ imply $B=C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A, B, C$ be sets with $B \subset  C$ and $C \subset  A$. Does $A\setminus B = A\setminus C$ imply $B=C$?

I am not sure what the "\" means, so I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: When you don't know what a mathematical symbol means, entering "mathematical symbols" into a search engine is advisable. [List of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)

Comment: $A\B= \{ x: x\in A and x\not \in B\}$

Comment: $A\setminus B = A\backslash B = A - B = A\cap B^c = \{x~:~x\in A~\text{and}~x\notin B\}$ are all equivalent ways of writing "set difference."

Comment: If $B$ and $C$ are both subsets of $A$ then the statement is true, but you should be aware that the notatin $A\setminus B$ makes sense even when $B$ is not a subset of $A$.  For example, if $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$, then $A\setminus B = \{1\}$.  And if in addition $C=\{2,4\}$, then $A\setminus C=\{1\}$, so then we have $A\setminus B=A\setminus C$ even though $B\ne C$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @user212083 you can accept one answer. i think all answers can be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does, since, if $B\subset A$, then $A\setminus (A\setminus B)=B$. So $A\setminus B = A\setminus C$ implies $A\setminus (A\setminus B) = A\setminus (A\setminus C)$, i.e.  $\,\,B=C$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $A\setminus B=A\setminus (B\cap A)$ and $A\setminus C=A\setminus (C\cap A)$.
 Given $B\subset C\subset A$.

$$\begin{align}A\setminus B&=A\setminus C\\\implies A\setminus (B\cap A)&=A\setminus (C\cap A)\\\implies B\cap A&=C\cap A\\\implies B&=C{[\text {using} B\subset C\subset A]}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669767/what-does-mean-in-math?rq=1), for *what* "∖" *means*. for other part:

you have $B \subset  C$. I prove $C \subset B$

Let $x\in C$. so $$ x\in A\ and\   x\notin (A\setminus C)$$ which means $$x\in A\ and\   x\notin (A\setminus B)$$ therefore $x\in B$

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality you can assume that $A$ is the *universal* set. Then your assumption means $B^c=C^c$; so $B=C$

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to good the answers already proposed here. I'd like to emphasize the fact that the assumption: $B\subset A$ **and** $C \subset A$ is crucial in order to conclude $B=C$.

**Example:** $A=\{1,2,3\}, B=\{1\},C=\{1,4\}\subset \Bbb N$ then $B \subset A$ but $\require{cancel} C \cancel{\subset} A$. Moreover, $A\setminus B = \{2,3\} = A\setminus C$, however, $B \neq C$.