# What does this "\" mathematics symbol mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am reading a paper which has a mathematical argument: $X \subset V \setminus \{0\}$.

Can anyone explain this statement to me? Especially the "$\setminus \{0\}$".

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: $X\subset V\setminus \{0\}$ means that $X$ is a subset of the set $V\setminus  \{0\}$, which is the set $V$ without the zero.  $$A\setminus B = A - B = \{x: x\in A \land x\notin B\} = A\cap B^c$$  $$ V\setminus \{0\} = V - \{0\} = \{x \mid x\in V \land x \notin \{0\}\}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is **set difference** (or [**relative complement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement)): $A\setminus B$ is the set of all things in $A$ but not $B$. That is, $$A\setminus B=\{x: x\in A, x\not\in B\}.$$ The latex code is "\setminus."

For example:

- $A\setminus A=\emptyset$, for every $A$.
- In your example, $V\setminus \{0\}$ is the set of all nonzero vectors in $V$.
- Note that $A\setminus B$ makes sense even if $B\not\subseteq A$, e.g.:

  - $\{1,2\}\setminus \{2, 3\}=\{1\}$.
  - $\{1,2\}\setminus \{3\}=\{1, 2\}$.

---

In particular, "$X\subset V\setminus \{0\}$" means "$X$ is a subset of $V\setminus \{0\}$," or more succinctly "$X$ is a set of nonzero vectors (in $V$)." *I'm guessing here that "$V$" is a vector space.*

Note that unfortunately the symbol "$\subset$" is sometimes used to denote proper subset and sometimes general subset; context will indicate whether $X$ is meant to be a set of nonzero vectors, or a set of some *but not all* nonzero vectors (almost certainly the former).

Answer (score 2):

In general, $A \setminus B = \{x \in A \mid x \not\in B\}$. Perhaps you're more familiar with the notation $A-B$. $V\setminus \{0\}$ denotes the set of all non-zero elements of $V$.

Answer (score -2):

The symbol $\setminus$ has several meanings, according to [wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:Set_Operations_and_Relations), e.g., it sometimes also denotes double cosets
$$
 K\left\backslash G \right/ H 
$$
Of course, in the context $V\setminus \{0\}$ it is the set difference. For a similar discussion, see

[What does "\" mean in math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669767/what-does-mean-in-math?rq=1)