# What does the \ notation mean in geometric structures plane separation postulate?

Tags: notation, plane-geometry

Referring to what the Plane Separation Postulate says about half-planes $H_1$ and $H_2$, it notes $H_1\cup H_2=\mathbb{P}\backslash l$. What does the \ mean between $\mathbb{P}$ and $l$?

Plane Separation Postulate: For every line $l$, the points that do not lie on $l$ form two disjoint, nonempty sets $H_1$ and $H_2$, called half-planes bounded by $l$, such that the following conditions are satisfied:

1. Each of $H_1$ and $H_2$ is convex.
2. If $P\in H_1$ and $Q\in H_2$, then $\overline{PQ}$ intersects $l$.

Here, in symbols, is what the postulate says about $H_1$ and $H_2$:

1. $H_1\cup H_2=\mathbb{P}\backslash l$.
2. etc.

Comment: Please hit the edit button and include definitions of your jargon and your notation. What are $H_1$ and $H_2$ and $\mathbb P$ and $l$? What is the statement of the Plane Separation Postulate? In general, when writing an MSE post, you should avoid assuming that your readers are familiar with jargon and specialized notation. As written, most readers will be unable to guess at the meaning of your post, without making unwarranted guesses, and because of this your post will attract close votes.

Comment: [Set difference](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Set_Difference)

Comment: *Plane Separation Postulate*: Given a line $l$ and a plane $P$ containing it, the points of the plane that do **not** lie on the line ... Thus the point must belong to plane $P$ and not belong to line $l$.

Comment: Thanks, @MauroALLEGRANZA! So, $H_1, H_2\in\mathbb{P}$ and are not on line $l$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "\" mean in math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669767/what-does-mean-in-math)